# Understanding Google Bigquery materialized views pricing

Tags: google-bigquery

inside Google BigQuery materialized view pricing documentation, i found this:

[image: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-intro#materialized_views_pricing]

This isn't clear at all, or rather: it isn't detailed.

In addition to what I'll pay (bytes processed during querying, byte processed during refresh time and bytes stored), I would like to know how much I'll pay. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what's mentioned above you'll pay if you are egressing data, performing streaming reads/writes into tables linked to the materialized view. This totally depends on your specific use case i.e. you may or may not incur them. However, the pricing you've shown will always be incurred.

[image: BigQuery Storage Read API General Network Usage]